# install gedit 3.15 on elementary OS Luna (= fork from Ubuntu 12.04 (LTS)): possible?

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, ubuntu-12.04, gtk3, gedit

I'm trying to do as the title says.
So far, the `./configure` step is stopped at this message:

```
checking for GEDIT... no
configure: error: Package requirements (
    libxml-2.0 >= 2.5.0
    glib-2.0 >= 2.40.0
    gio-2.0 >= 2.40.0
    gmodule-2.0
    gtk+-3.0 >= 3.15.7
    gtksourceview-3.0 >= 3.15.3
    libpeas-1.0 >= 1.7.0
    libpeas-gtk-1.0 >= 1.7.0
    gsettings-desktop-schemas
) were not met:

Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.40.0' but version of GLib is 2.32.4
Requested 'gio-2.0 >= 2.40.0' but version of GIO is 2.32.4
Requested 'gtk+-3.0 >= 3.15.7' but version of GTK+ is 3.4.2
Requested 'gtksourceview-3.0 >= 3.15.3' but version of gtksourceview is 3.4.2
No package 'libpeas-1.0' found
No package 'libpeas-gtk-1.0' found
No package 'gsettings-desktop-schemas' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GEDIT_CFLAGS
and GEDIT_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

are the versions requested possible to install on the system i'm currently on? (cf title)
at any rate i'd just want to try a newer version of gedit: which one can i install given my current OS?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to build the latest stable release of gedit (3.16) on an older platform, you'll likely need to build all of its dependencies. This is usually achieved by using a separate development environment, like [jhbuild](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/Jhbuild).

The latest version of gedit that can be build on Ubuntu 12.04 is the one that shipped with Ubuntu 12.04, i.e. gedit 3.4.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i'm a little confused: is it totally impossible to create a newer version of gedit than 3.4 on ubuntu, or can it be done using what you mention, jhbuild?

Comment: You can use jhbuild — up to a certain point, because jhbuild cannot build low level system components that can be required when building the whole dependency stack needed by gedit. Your best bet is to set up a development environment using jhbuild, following the wikipage I linked, but if that does not work you will have to update to a more recent version of Ubuntu.